# every trigonalisable matrix is diagonalisable by blocks

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening ,
How can one show that every trigonalisable matrix is diagonalisable by blocks ? (in a algebric closed field )

Comment: "Trigonalisable"? Is that like *triangularizable*?

Comment: Could spring for "digonalisable" too :). No problem, I just wanted to make sure

Comment: What is diagonalizable by blocks? In an algebraic closed field you can always obtain the Jordan normal form ...

Comment: sorry I'm french , I don't know how to translate it in english but it means that the matrix is similar to an upper triangulaire matrice

Comment: the problem I got is to prove the decomposition of jordan ,in an algebric closed field we need to show that the trigonalisable matrix is diagonalisable by blocks to use the lemma that says every nilpotent matrix is similar to the jordan blocks